# How to get the website's Base URL without setting it manually?

Tags: php, url, uri, superglobals

I am trying to achieve a means by which I can get the base URL of a website without having to define it manually and regardless of any other additional query strings or folders added later

Example

If the url is

> http://localhost/testsite/action/login or
>
> http://192.154.15.02/~testuser/testsite?action=login

The output should be

> http://localhost/testsite and
>
> http://192.154.15.02/~testuser/testsite

respectively

I have tried using this and other related variations

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

But it always changes based on the added values in the url.

Can I please get some assistance.

Thanks

Comment: There's no generic approach for *every* configuration. In particular your first example would use RewriteRules or PathInfo, while the second with peruser webroots is rather uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

For absolute paths, it is sometimes helpful to define constants like:

```
  // which page are we on?  eg /some/path/to/script.php
  if( ! defined( 'WEB_PATH' ) ) define('WEB_PATH', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

  // web root dir. eg /some/path/to
  //if( ! defined( 'WEB_ROOT' ) ) define('WEB_ROOT', dirname(WEB_PATH));
  if( ! defined( 'WEB_ROOT' ) ) {
          $path = dirname(WEB_PATH);
          // avoid "//" at root
          if ( $path == '/' ) $path = '';
          define('WEB_ROOT', $path);
  }


  // what is the file name only?  // eg script.php
  if( ! defined( 'WEB_FILE' ) ) define('WEB_FILE', basename(WEB_PATH));

  // physical file path (system).  eg: /var/www/html/yoursite
  if( ! defined( 'ABS_ROOT' ) ) define('ABS_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```